# Running command on remote database (oracle) from local server using sqlplus

Tags: oracle

I want to run a command on remote database (oracle) from local server using sqlplus, eg:

```
sqlplus user/pass@db "command"
```

What's the syntax for it?

I want to use the command exit (from database) just to test something in a unix script.

Answer (score 2):

try this in the below example i am calling test_procedure.

```
sqlplus "username/password@tns_name" <<\!

exec test_procedure();

!
```

Comment: Use this from comment --> sqlplus "username/password@tns_name" <<!

exec test_procedure();

!